# TypeError: Cannot read property <template name> of undefined when creating package

Tags: meteor

I am trying to create a package for Meteor, unsuccessfully unfortunately. I'm on Meteor 1.8.1. My goal is to make a template for a button that I can use in my application like this `{{> testButton}}` (I am just trying it out atm).

**package.js**

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'button-test',
    version: '0.0.1',
    summary: '',
    git: '',
    documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.use(['ecmascript']);
    api.use(['session', 'templating'], ['client', 'server']);
    api.mainModule('button-test.js');
});

Package.onTest(function (api) {
    api.use('ecmascript');
    api.use('tinytest');
    api.use('button-test');
    api.mainModule('button-test-tests.js');
});
```

**button-test.js**

```
// Variables exported by this module can be imported by other packages and
// applications. See button-test-tests.js for an example of importing.
import './testButton.js';
```

**testButton.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

  Template.testButton.events({
    'click #buttonT': () =>
        console.log('Clicked the button')
 });
```

**testButton.html**

```
<template name="testButton"><button id="buttonT">TEST</button></template>
```

I have some problems with this;

- Running the code like this returns the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'testButton' of undefined`. So there is a problem with Template, but I don't know what it is, since I have added it with api.use
- When I try to add `import ./testButton.html` to testButton.js I get the error `Error: Cannot find module './testButton.html'`

I looked at the source code for accounts-ui-unstyled, but this is written on an older meteor version.

Does anybody have an idea as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `api.mainModule`, I solved it by having my Package.onUse like this:

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
    api.use(['templating', 'blaze'], 'client');
    api.use('ecmascript');
    api.addFiles(['button-test.js'], 'client');
});
```

After using the addFiles instead of mainModule, I could import the html and the Template problem disappeared. I have no idea why this works and mainModule does not, but hey, it does.